# BLS hash as a group element exponent?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, random-oracle-model, bls-signature

In [BLS short signatures paper](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480516.pdf), the authors describe a hash function $H\colon\ \{0, 1\}^∗ → G^∗$, where $G$ is a Gap-Diffie-Hellman group.
They present a structure where a standard hash is used on a field element, and then mapped to a subgroup of $G$, later to be used in the security proof as a random oracle.
How would the security proof change (or break) if we'll simply use an exponentiation of some generator of $G$?
 i.e., to have $H(m) := g^m$ for some generator $g$.

Comment: see here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11358/why-is-a-simple-hash-into-g-2-for-certain-pairing-based-crypto-not-possible/11359#11359

Comment: Thanks @DrLecter. In your answer you demonstrated an insecure hash using $H: \{0, 1\}^* \rightarrow G$ as $H(M) = H'(M)P$, using the same generator $P$ used to create the public key $X = xP$.
Wouldn't breaking it be avoided if instead we'll define $H(M) = H'(M)Q$ where the discrete log from $Q$ to $P$ is **unknown**?
Or is the problem is to find such a $Q$ in the first place?...

Comment: Finding such a Q is not a problem in this setting. Yes this would make the attack outlined ineffective. But the proof strategy breaks down.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a secure hash function. For example, one can easily break the 
collision resistance property: let $q$ be the order of $g$, then $m$ and $m+q$ have the same hash value, $H(m+q)=g^{m+q}=g^m=H(m)$.

Comment: Thanks! What if I'll change that to $H(m) = g^{H'(m)}$ for some CRH $H'$ ?

Comment: You can restrict the domain of H to $\mathbb{Z}_q$, which solves this problem. And yes, you could use a CRH H' tonmap to this domain first.

Comment: It should be $\mathbb{Z}_q$.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it solves this specific attack but renders BLS' security proof useless?...

Comment: Are you refering to the comment under your question? Then yes.

Comment: Well, at second thought, the proof is considering a random oracle, which is impractical anyway. 
I think the actual question would be what is the difference of using the suggested method (having $H(m) = g^{H'(m)}$ and the concrete hash function described in the paper...

Comment: Are you familiar with proofs in the random oracle model? Their hash function can be used to approximate a random oracle, i.e., instantiate it in practice. So what do you mean by impractical? And it seems unlikely that you will come up with a security proof using your instantiation.

Comment: As far as I know, and as suggested in "Random Oracles are Practical" paper by Bellare, there are recommendations to use concrete hash functions (or symmetric ciphers) to instantiate what's *believed* to be good enough to fulfill the role of a random oracle, which is (probably) a stronger requirement than pre-image and collision resistance.
So my problem here, is that I don't know exactly what disqualifies the suggested function from instantiating the hash function (if I limit its domain and so on)...

Comment: ... In fact, I think it would be more precise to say that the requirements are to be indistinguishable from random oracle, i.e. a PRF (rather than a cryptographic hash function), which is believed to be achieved with symmetric ciphers and hash functions. 
If you agree with the latter... can $g^{H'(m)}$ be counted as a PRF?
Otherwise, where am I wrong? (oh, and thank you for the discussion!)

Comment: The point is that you would have to show a security proof (euf-cma of bls), i.e., a reduction to some hard problem. The reduction to CDH (or co-CDh, dependingnon the pairing type) will not work for your proposed function. So you would have to come up with a new proof for bls (and this seems hard with your proposal).

Comment: The only assumption on $H$ is that it is a random oracle, as is used in the proof... So the instantiation should be a hash function, but not necessarily a standard like SHA256 or similar... I assume I can use a pedersen commitment with a random factor just as well? I'm interested in such construction so I can build an efficient zero-knowledge proof of knowledge of the message, which seems to be very hard when I'm using BLS suggestion for a hash function

Comment: The proof needs to program the random oracle in a certain way such that the reduction works. If you can show that somehow for your suggestion, then you are fine. But you have to do that ;)